# Shopify - Receive emails through a contact page via the API

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

There is no code here,
I am just having a problem trying to find out how to make my `contact us` page functional inside my shopify app.

This link https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/os/using-themes/change-the-layout/add-contact-form explains how to create contact page in shopify. But I am creating a shopify app using `nextjs` and I am having my own `contact us` page. The issue is that I can not find in the docs how to integrate that page with shopify API so that the merchant receives emails from the customers through it.

Answer (score 1):

In the [docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/theme-tags#form?itcat=partner_blog&itterm=build_forms_on_shopify) there is an example of the form output:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/contact" class="contact-form" method="post">
  <input name="form_type" type="hidden" value="contact" />
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" />
  ...
</form>
```

Note the post action here - you should be able to post to `/contact` to post the contact form data.

Comment: I am trying it, it is not working. Actually it worked from the customer's Point Of View POV as it forwarded me to the reCaptcha and redirected the customer back. But from the merchant's POV no email was received. While the contact page that is not created through the api in the store works properly and it sends emails.

Comment: Note that I edited the form to be `action="https://mystorename.myshopify.com/contact"` if you write `action="/contact"` from the app's url the page will not be found and you won't even be forwarded to the reCaptcha.

Comment: Ah, if the request is coming from a different URL you might be running into some CORS errors that Shopify may have in place. I assumed the Next.js app was running inside the theme. Were you seeing any CORS errors (in console) when you tried to post to the `https://mystorename.myshopify.com/contact` URL?

Comment: No I am not seeing any errors, it actually works perfectly fine from the client side. The thing is that it doesn't send this message to the merchant. I am assuming that there's a kind of "permission" needed to be set so that the storefront recognizes this form as a legit form allowed to pass the message to the `/contact` !!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot post a form on a Shopify Page resource to your own custom App. That is just not allowed. You do have two choices. You can inject a script tag into the Page which will run some Javascript that could contact your App, or your App can setup an App Proxy, and then you place callbacks from your form on a Page to your App that way.